# Shading faces of solid (described using using \parametricplotThreeD)

Tags: pstricks, 3d, pst-3dplot

Does anyone know how to shade only one of the faces of a solid whose faces are described using parametricplot? For example, shade the faces of the solid below? In general, how to color each of the sides with different colors/patterns? It might be necessary to change the whole code (?)

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1)(2.5,2)
    \psset{unit=2cm,Alpha=70,Beta=15,fillstyle=solid}
    %\psgrid
    \pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=gray,xMin=0,xMax=2,yMin=0,yMax=2,zMin=0,zMax=1.5]

    \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(1,-0.1,0)(1,0.1,0)
    \pstThreeDPut(1,-0.2,0.1){$1$}

    \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(-0.1,1,0)(0.1,1,0)
    \pstThreeDPut(-0.3,1,0.1){$1$}

    \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(-0.1,0,1)(0.1,0,1)
    \pstThreeDPut(-0.3,-0.3,1){$1$}


    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,90){%
     t cos %
     0 %
     t sin}%
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,90){%
     t cos %
     t sin %
     0}%
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,90){%
     t cos %
     t sin %
     t sin }%
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1){%
     0 %
     1 %
     t}%
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1){%
     0 %
     t %
     1}%
     \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1){%
     0 %
     0 %
     t}%

    \psline[linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(1.2,-0.6)(0.5,-0.3)
    \put(1.3,-0.7){$x^2+y^2=1$}

    \psline[linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-1.1,0.5)(-0.4,0.35)
    \put(-2.2,0.5){$x^2+z^2=1$}

    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-1.5)(5,3.5)
 \psset{unit=2cm,Alpha=70,Beta=15,fillstyle=solid}
    %\psgrid
  \pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=gray,xMin=0,xMax=2,yMin=0,yMax=2,zMin=0,zMax=1.5]
  \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(1,-0.1,0)(1,0.1,0)
  \pstThreeDPut(1,-0.2,0.1){$1$}
  \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(-0.1,1,0)(0.1,1,0)
  \pstThreeDPut(-0.3,1,0.1){$1$}
  \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=lightgray]{-}(-0.1,0,1)(0.1,0,1)
  \pstThreeDPut(-0.3,-0.3,1){$1$}
  \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,90)
      { t cos 0 t sin }
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50,opacity=0.5]{%Build a closed apth:
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,%
     linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,90){%
     t cos t sin 0}
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,%
    plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1){%
     0 1 t}
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](90,0)
      { t cos t sin t sin }
}

    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1)
      { 0 t 1}
    \parametricplotThreeD[linecolor=black,linewidth=.5pt,xPlotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve,arrows=-](0,1)
      { 0 0 t}
    \psline[linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(1.2,-0.6)(0.5,-0.3)
    \put(1.3,-0.7){$x^2+y^2=1$}
    \psline[linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-1.1,0.5)(-0.4,0.35)
    \put(-2.2,0.5){$x^2+z^2=1$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]